# Permission Denied when downloading Drupal

Tags: linux, permissions

```
 /var/www$ wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz
```

This results in:

```
    --2012-02-08 21:20:17--  http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.drupal.org... 64.50.233.100, 64.50.236.52
Connecting to ftp.drupal.org|64.50.233.100|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2728271 (2.6M) [application/x-gzip]
drupal-7.0.tar.gz: Permission denied

Cannot write to `drupal-7.0.tar.gz' (Permission denied).
eyedea@eyedea-ER912AA-ABA-SR1810NX-NA620:/var/www$ ^C
eyedea@eyedea-ER912AA-ABA-SR1810NX-NA620:/var/www$ wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz
--2012-02-08 21:46:34--  http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.drupal.org... 64.50.236.52, 64.50.233.100
Connecting to ftp.drupal.org|64.50.236.52|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2728271 (2.6M) [application/x-gzip]
drupal-7.0.tar.gz: Permission denied

Cannot write to `drupal-7.0.tar.gz' (Permission denied).
```

I checked the permissions of /var/www and i can't change them. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally normal. your `/var/www` directory belongs to **root** user and **root** group with those rights `drwxr-xr-x`.

It's far more better to have `/var/www` belonging to root, because it will forbid possible security flaws in **apache** or **php** to write and change source code on this server.

What you can do about that :

1. Make your wget with root rights. For instance :

   `$ sudo wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz`
   or

   `$ su -c "wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz"`
2. Download it from your $HOME and untar it afterwards

   `$ cd ~; wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.0.tar.gz`
3. Ignore those security recommendations and change rights of `/var/www`

   `` $ sudo chown `id -u`:`id -g` /var/www ``

**EDIT** : If you have broken your `/var/www` tree with a `chmod -R 777 /var/www/*` and haven't burn in hell, you can thank god and quickly execute those commands before he comes for you :

```
$ sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
$ sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: i should've just used sudo but before i got your response I ended up changing permissions to 777. @_@. What would you recommend I change them back to?